# Jquery slide toggle breaks

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, html-lists

I've switched from using css to show/hide to javascript/jquery instead of using the css to use the slide feature. My menu is all horizontal, no verticle. The slide technically works, but if I go from the child of a child link then diagonal to the child, it breaks completely. Maybe my logic is just wrong? Animate was cool, but it didn't actually slide in from the left (I guess because of the list it starts as a list top down then goes up, then slides from the left), so unless there is a way to make that work, I need slide to work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tp3N/)

Again I suggest to go to my test site to see what is actually going on. make it drop down to the child of "uhoh", then while hovering over one of the children, diagonally go to "bam", then out to the left, then back over projects. If that doesn't mess it up, just randomly make it hover, it will mess up when you get out and hover back over "projects" the parent.

[My Test Site](http://imengine.gofreeserve.com/fileshare/fileshare2/index2.php)

Comment: Just a suggestion, the fading on hover can be done much more efficiently with css3's transition property

Comment: Upon looking further into your usage, I think that transitions would css is much more efficient for what you are trying to accomplish, both code wise and browser-efficiency wise. take a look at transition:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transition

Comment: For browser compatibility, and being I use IE myself, I can't go to transitions right now as from what I've read they are incompatible. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp). If anyone could please take a look at my Jquery and see if they can see what's up. This has been quite a mess of a menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was me calling a class in jquery that was a name for more than one child ul.

```
// Add the 'hover' event listener to our drop down class 
$("#navbar li.has_children").hover(function() {
    // When the event is triggered, grab the current element 'this' and 
    // find it's children '.sub_navigation' and display/hide them
    //$(this).find("ul.sub_menu").first().animate({ width: "toggle" }, 100);
    $(this).find("ul.sub_menu").first().toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 200);
});
```

This needed another hover function called and change the second to #navbar li ul li.has_children to ensure it is toggle on the correct one. This still caused me problems, so I switched to a show/hide with hover instead of toggle and they pull correclty now.

Now if they would just stop flashing....

p.s.
switched to the :has() in jquery to call per structure and not classes. Thanks Austin!

Answer (score 0):

From someone who has made this type of navigation many times, there is no need for such complexity within your classnames and markup. Take a look at this fiddle for a simplified version:

http://jsfiddle.net/fQsr9/

This is much less overwhelming to look at, and should make it easier to track and manipulate with jQuery

Comment: I understand what you mean, but unless there is another way to use ajax to load a page dynamically then that has to be in the link on my markup. With that, I also tried using jquery with the hierarchy names in the list but it wasn't working, and it does work with the class names. That is all that is there so i don't have the knowledge to make it any more simple, and i can't make it as simple ad you posted for the reasons I just posted, although I would like to. This functionality is what I want in there.

Comment: I mean the functionality that I have in my code is what i want. Making it that bare loses it's functionality. I have the correct structure per lists, which is what you posted an example of. My issue is the toggle in jquery.

Comment: The class names are not necessary at all. Take a look at the jQuery :has() selector. With this, you can select all <li>s that may have a <ul>, eliminating the need for a has_children or submenu classes. Having more classes just clutters your code and makes it more confusing to work with. Also, I am not saying to take my example, but to use it as an example and strip your code down.

Comment: That's what I was hoping was on jquery; has(). No idea that was there, and now I can take out the classes. I appreciate it. Also found the flaw on my code and will post an answer. Thanks @Austin.